# How to parse the specific data data from any website in Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I want to parse the specific data data from any website in jsoup. I just write a code like this, I want the product data from any website.

```
public class Example {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

         String url="http://www.genesyslab.com";//this is given by user in text box.
        Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
       Elements links = doc.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
          if(link.text().equals("Products")){
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href") +link.text());
          }
        }
        // get the value from href attribute
      //  System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("a[href]","product"));

    }
catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here I will get the output link:

> /products/index.aspx   Products

but my aim is to find all the child link coming under the Products in text format, if you visit http://www.genesyslab.com then mouse over to Products it will shows product overview, contact centre ivr, cloud. I want to parse these text values only.

Likely if I go to Solutions tab then it will extract all the child link in text format (customer service solution, enterprise solution).

Comment: what specific data you want ? add some example with some standard links

Comment: Elements links = doc.select("body"); ->you are not selecting links but the body only

Comment: Let's "http://www.genesyslab.com".In main menu there are products,solutions ,services,when i type "http://www.genesyslab.com/products (in my design)then it will shows me all products (contact center ivr,cloud,web customer services .....like this in text format)

Comment: The URL in this question now redirects to a different site, and I don't think the description of what was required at the time matches up with what the site contains now. This is exactly the danger of relying on external links in questions. I think this needs to be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

To select the links you really want to do

```
        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
          if(link.text().equals("product")){
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href")));
          }
        }
```

i.e. select all link elements and then check if their text is "product"... this isn't the most elegant solution but seems to be what you're aiming at.

Comment: but the problem is that i am only getting the product link and i want all the child link and its text value also..

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're aiming at. Could you add some more examples to your question of what you've tried and what you want to get out i.e. I run this command and want it to print out this with this input.